# running into issues training tesseract

Tags: tesseract

I am new to tesseract and am a bit confused with the different directories in the github page.

The tesserac-ocr code base is what I installed. That installed a tessdata directory in /usr/local/share/tessdata/

So now while training tesseract I run the following command -

```
# tesseract img.tif img box.train
```

I get the following error

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
```

Obviously its not able to find the tessdata folder.

So now I obtained the tessdata directory from github (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata). Then pointed the TESSDATA_PREFIX to the downloaded tessdata from github. Does not change anything. I get the following error -

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica
read_params_file: Can't open box.train
```

So my question is what should the tessdata be pointed to? Where does tesseract obtain the box.train from in the training command?

Comment: Did you create and check a box.train file? If not you have to create the box.train first with `tesseract img.tif img batch.nochop makebox`. Afterwards you will have to check the box file if your characters are detected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One of most stupid things you can do as novice is try to train tesseract ;-)

Next: 3.03 version is not in official github.com repo (btw: 3.03 was never official released... it was just Ubuntu that made that release.)

Next: if you installed tesseract correctly (from source) box.train is installed. You you installed from Ubuntu packages/repo (I do not think so, because in that case tesseract would not used /usr/local/... ) than you should contact packager how (s)he packaged tesseract.

Comment: They moved from code.google.com to github but did not update their documentation. The problem is they changed the way the code is packaged and distributed. I installed it from source.

Comment: Move to github.com is documented as other project did - on main page.